# threejs mesh with alpha mask, cast shadow

Tags: three.js, shadow

A single plane with an alpha mask must cast shadows. It does but for the whole plane- not applying the alpha mask-.

Searching around I've found that adding a customDeptMaterial to the mesh should do it:

```
var customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
            depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
            alphaMap: alphaTex,  
            alphaTest: 0.5
        } );
figures.customDepthMaterial = customDepthMaterial;
```

Not that I am very sure of what's going on exactly but I must be missing something because it keeps casting the whole plane

Please see the complete fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/truji7/gj7az9eo/34/

How can I cast the "alpha filtered" shadow?

Comment: why not a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PointLights](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/PointLight) are the only type of light that utilizes [MeshDistanceMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshDistanceMaterial) instead of [MeshDepthMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshDepthMaterial).

```
object.customDistanceMaterial = new THREE.MeshDistanceMaterial( {
    alphaMap: alphaTex,
    alphaTest: 0.5,
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eocg56wL/)

Comment: your fiddle doesn't appear to be working anymore? Is this incorrect with the latest version of three.js?